# Angular 2 - FormArray + File Input + Native Element

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload

I'm working on a Reactive Form on Angular 2 but I'm getting stuck.

On my FormArray there is a upload file field, I'm using `@ViewChild` to get the file and `forEach` to loop through the `FormArray`, the data works fine but the file input doesn't. I'm getting the same file uploaded twice.

Can anybody help me with that?

Thank you so much!

**add.component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('pictureInput') pictureInput: any;

bArray.forEach((element) => {
   // Picture Upload
   // Create an ID for the picture to be uploaded.
   const picUpId = this.createID();
   // Connects to the UPLOAD service to store the file
                        this.uploadService.uploadFile(this.pictureInput.nativeElement.files[0], picUpId, 'uploads/' + id + '/').then(
     (picData) => {
          // Extract the DownloadURL from the object.
          picData.ref.getDownloadURL().then(
               (picDownURL) => {
                    const bPicture = new ImageModel(picDownURL, id);
               }
          );

      }
);
```

**add.component.html**

```
<input type="file" formControlName="bPicture" #pictureInput>
```

Comment: Because `pictureInput` here is single variable not changing with formArray, try to use it with index or something else

Comment: Hey @PardeepJain thanks for the suggestion, I'm new in this thing could you give me an example? I tried getting the index of the `@ViewChild` but it didn't work.